# Program that reads and writes to a txt/log file

Tags: java, file, filewriter, file-read

i'm really new to programming and I have basic knowledge.

I'm trying to make a program that:

1. Reads the path of an already existing file
2. Reads the string that I want to extract from the existing file.
3. Reads the path for creating a new file.
4. Creates a file with the specified path from point 3. which contains the selected words from point 2.

For example If I have a log/txt file. From it i wanna extract all the strings that I'm reading from the keyboard at point 2.

After this I want all these strings to be written in a new log/txt file.

I hope you got the idea of what I'm trying to do.

This is what I wrote until now but I kinda got stuck in ideas and since I'm still learning the coding syntax it's pretty hard to realize it.

```
package com.kwextractor;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Main {
    public static String inputFilePath;
    public static String outputFilePath;
    public static String textToGet;


        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Scanner filePathIn = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner inputText = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner filePathOut = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter file path:");
        inputFilePath = filePathIn.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Enter the string you want to extract:");
        textToGet = inputText.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Enter the path of the exported file:");
        outputFilePath = filePathOut.nextLine();

        File inputFile = new File(inputFilePath +".txt");

        BufferedReader inputReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inputFile));
        String nextLine;
        while ((nextLine = inputReader.readLine()) != null)
        {
            if (nextLine.equals(textToGet)) {

                BufferedWriter writer = null;
                try {
                    File outputFile = new File(outputFilePath+".txt");
                    System.out.println(outputFile.getCanonicalPath());
                    writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(outputFile));
                    writer.write(textToGet);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    try {
                        // Close the writer regardless of what happens...
                        writer.close();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you're ever stuck in ideas, the *last* thing you want to do is present us with an incomplete question.  Take the time to go back to the whiteboard and map out specifically what you want to accomplish with your program.  Then work towards *accomplishing* it.  When you get stuck on some specific part towards that, then come back and ask us.  You'll be better equipped for it then.

Comment: for educational purposes this code is already a harsh bit of work... try to -really- understand the code, e.g. exception handling itself is already a big deal since there is much code out there without sufficient exception handling... the most time it looks like ` catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }` or even better `//TODO`, also streams, buffers, and even that there is no reason to make a variable public, neither is there a reason in your code to make it static. ( I hope these are enough "ideas" you can do to learn programming )

Comment: @makoto I dont see any incomplete question here. I explained exactly what I want to create and also put the code hoping someone will try to explain me what I did wrong because of course the program is not running and maybe someone can correct me.

Comment: Yes, the fact that you want us to explain how you can create your entire application is what makes your question "incomplete" *at best*.  You can't just expect us to do that here.  We can help you with parts but you have to put the effort in.  I strongly encourage you to exercise what I had suggested above.

Comment: @moneydhaze I will get all these tips and try apply them. thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. Do 4 smaller projects, each one doing one of the steps you listed.
2. Re-Do this project using hard-coded paths instead of input from the console to avoid some complexity.
3. Once #2 works, I would add in the console input, but add checks around input using **StringUtils.isBlank** to handle erronious input.

In short, you are trying to do way too many things all at once. Programming can be a lot like a math equation, you only want 1 unknown at a time.

Comment: That's a great idea. First I was thinking to make different classes that I would call them in the main function after. But I will try this thing you've said, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So guys.. I tried to rework the program and search more about how I can accomplish what I want to do, where I got stuck is at the part where I need to create the file and write to it. 
I would appreciate if someone could tell me what I did wrong in the part where I need to write to the new file.
Here is the code that I remade:

```
    package com.readtxtfile;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    private static String inputFilePath;
    private static String  textToGet;
    private static void readInputFile()
    {
        String line1 = null;

        Scanner input1 = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Insert the input file path:");
        inputFilePath = input1.nextLine();


        try {
            FileReader readInput = new FileReader(inputFilePath+".txt");
            BufferedReader bufferedInput = new BufferedReader(readInput);
            line1 = bufferedInput.readLine();
            if (line1 != null)
                System.out.println("FILE LOADED SUCCESFULLY");

            bufferedInput.close();

        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            System.out.println(
                    "Unable to open file '" + inputFilePath + "'");
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println(
                    "Error reading file '" + inputFilePath + "'");
        }
    }
    private static void textSearch()
    {
        Scanner input2 = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Insert the text you want to extract:");
        textToGet = input2.nextLine();
    }
    private static void writeOutputFile()
    {

        Scanner input3 = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Insert the output file path:");
        String outputFilePath = input3.nextLine();
            Scanner input4 = new Scanner(inputFilePath);

            int lineNumber = 0;
            while (input4.hasNextLine()) {
                String line2 = input4.nextLine();
                lineNumber++;
                if(textToGet.equals(line2))
                {
                    File output_file = new File(outputFilePath +".txt");
                    FileWriter writeOutput = null;
                    BufferedWriter bufferedInput = new BufferedWriter(writeOutput);
                    try {
                        writeOutput = new FileWriter(output_file +".txt");
                        writeOutput.write(line2);
                    } catch (IOException e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
                }
            }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
     readInputFile();
     textSearch();
     writeOutputFile();
    }
}
```